# How to display image file from sftp remote server in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, sftp, paramiko

1. We have 2 servers. One of them is for media files and the other one is for django project server(ngnx+gunicorne).
2. Our media server is local(internal). We want to access to media server from inside the project with sftp storage package which includes paramiko. we don't want to access media server via URL (http,https).
3. `HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)` can display the image file as a big picture  but we want to pass the image file to django template for display in html file like   `<a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{images}}" alt=""></a>`
4. We know HttpResponse is not a good solution but we use it below code for explained our problem.

```
# view
def coursesPageView(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(is_published=True)
    image_data =[imageRespone(data) for data in courses]

    data = {
            'published_courses_list':courses,
            'images' : image_data
        }
    return render(request, 'pages/course2.html', data)
    

def imageRespone(valid_image):
    if sfs.exists(valid_image.image.name):
        file = sfs._read(valid_image.image.name)
        type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(valid_image.image.name)        
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse('404 Not Found')
```

```
#course2.html
 <a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{images}}" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: One thing you could do, is instead of creating an HttpResponse, create a string with the base64 encoded image. Format should be like `data:image/png;base64,<base64-encoded-image-data>`. This should work as `img src` in the html. I use this for very small images only, not sure how well it works for normal size images.

Comment: Another suggestion: Have `img src` point to a django URL and in the corresponding view, fetch the image in question and return the HttpResponse.

Comment: Image file data created with ```file_data = sfs._read(valid_image.image.name)``` command. Is this data **base64-encoded-image-data format**? If not how can **base64-encoded-image-data**  be created from **file_data**? @treuss

Comment: Assuming that `_read` returns bytes, use [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is mounting a shared drive into your webserver pointing to your media server (Samba for linux). Then with Django you can specify the localisation of your statics file.

For example :

```py
import os

MEDIA_URL        = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT       = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.sep, 'srv', 'media'))

STATIC_URL       = '/app/static/'
STATIC_ROOT      = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.sep, 'srv', 'static'))
```

Pay attention to the permissions between the web server and the mounted folder.